# How to impute test data with imputed values of training data with GridSearchCV and sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I am trying to improve my submissions for the Kaggle House Prices Competition found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-data-for-ml-course/overview). I'm working with the Iowa data available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-data-for-ml-course/data). 
I'm trying to train and test my model using a pipeline(sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline), cross-validating with GridSearchCV(sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) and using and using XGBRegressor(xgboost.XGBRegressor). The features selected had categorical data and NaN values that had to be imputed (sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer().
Initial setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Path of the file to read.
iowa_file_path = '../input/train.csv'

original_home_data = pd.read_csv(iowa_file_path)

home_data = original_home_data.copy()

# delete rows where SalePrice is Nan
home_data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['SalePrice'], inplace=True)

# Create a target object and call it y
y = home_data.SalePrice

# Create X
features = ['LotArea', 'YearBuilt', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'FullBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd']
extra_features = ['OverallCond', 'GarageArea', 'LotFrontage', 'OverallQual', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'GrLivArea', 'MoSold']
categorical_data = ['LotShape', 'MSZoning', 'Neighborhood', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'Foundation', 'KitchenQual']

features.extend(extra_features)
features.extend(categorical_data)

X = home_data[features]
```

The categorical data was one hot encoded by:

```
X = pd.get_dummies(X, prefix='OHE', columns=categorical_data)
```

Columns with missing values were gathered by:

```
cols_with_missing = (col for col in X.columns if X[col].isnull().any())
for col in cols_with_missing:
    X[col + '_was_missing'] = X[col].isnull()
```

The training and validation data were then split:

```
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1, test_size=0.25)
train_X, val_X = train_X.align(val_X, join='left', axis=1)
```

The pipeline was then created to impute mean for NaN with the regressor

```
    my_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer()), ('xgbrg', XGBRegressor())])
param_grid = {
    'xgbrg__n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000], 
    'xgbrg__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1]
}
fit_params = {
    'xgbrg__early_stopping_rounds': 10,
    'xgbrg__verbose': False,
    'xgbrg__eval_set': [(np.array(val_X), val_y)]
}
```

I then initialized the cross validator:

```
searchCV = GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, cv=5, param_grid=param_grid, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

I then fitted my cross validator:

```
searchCV = GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, cv=5, param_grid=param_grid, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

and fit the model (**take note of this next line**):

```
searchCV.fit(X=np.array(train_X), y=train_y, **fit_params)
```

I then did the same for the test data (one hot encoding, getting columns with NaN,)

```
# path to file you will use for predictions
test_data_path = '../input/test.csv'

# read test data file using pandas
test_data = pd.read_csv(test_data_path)

# create test_X which comes from test_data but includes only the columns you used for prediction.
original_test_X = test_data[features]

test_X = original_test_X.copy()

# to one hot encode the data
test_X = pd.get_dummies(test_X, prefix='OHE', columns=categorical_data)

for col in cols_with_missing:
    test_X[col + '_was_missing'] = test_X[col].isnull()

# to align the training and test data and discard columns not in the training data
X, test_X = X.align(test_X, join='inner', axis=1)
```

I then tried to transform the test data with the average from the training data to impute the NaN values in the test data:

```
test_X = my_pipeline.named_steps['imputer'].transform(test_X)
```

I then get this error:

```
NotFittedError: This SimpleImputer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

So i can't even use this line for prediction:

```
test_preds = searchCV.predict(test_X)
```

1. What might be wrong here?
2. How can I use my pipeline to transform another dataset after fitting?

If i try creating a new SimpleImputer() instance for the test data and imputing for NaN and performing a fit_transform:

```
test_pipeline = SimpleImputer()
test_X = test_pipeline.fit_transform(test_X)
```

and I add and run:

```
test_preds = searchCV.predict(test_X)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 72 features per sample, expected 74
```

3. What is wrong here?

Comment: Your pipeline "`my_pipeline`" is not fitted, but `searchCV` is? You say "`So i can't even use this line for prediction`", but have you even tried it?

Comment: @VivekKumar, My understanding of GridSearchCV is that it fits the pipeline (both the Imputer and XGBRegressor) multiple times for cross-validation, so the pipeline itself does not have to be fitted? **"So i can't even use this for prediction"**, that's because the `NotFittedError` comes before that line. The tutorial i followed for my application can be found  [here](https://www.kaggle.com/aashita/advanced-pipelines-tutorial)

Comment: No. GridSearchCV will clone your supplied estimator (the pipeline in this case) and fit that with all the data and best parameters "after" searching for the hyperparameters using cross-validation. So `searchCV.predict()` will work. Check out the `"refit"` param of `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: The whole reason why you are getting the error `"ValueError: X has 72 features per sample, expected 74"` because `searchCV` is fitted on different data (as I said above) and you are sending different data to it. Please show how you one-hot encoded the `test_X` before sending it to simpleImputer?

Comment: @VivekKumar regarding your first comment. I know about refit and left it at its default (True). Regarding your second question, I used the same way I one hot encoded my training data: `# to one hot encode the data`  
`test_X = pd.get_dummies(test_X, prefix='OHE', columns=categorical_data)`. I think the problem might be that not all the categorical data in the training set exists in the test set, so the one hot encoding of the test set does not have as many features.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "This SimpleImputer instance is not fitted yet" error when refining my model at the Missing Data stage. After a lot of trial and error, the following did the trick for me:

Prep your test data in the same loop where you are prepping the training data. Basically, the "for col in cols_with_missing" loop should be run for training and test data simultaneously. I am a newbie in this field as well (just started last week), but I am guessing this error might be occurring due to a mismatch in the columns if you run that col loop separately for training and testing data.

my code snippet which worked:

```
cols_with_missing = (col for col in X_train.columns 
                                 if X_train[col].isnull().any())
for col in cols_with_missing:
    imputed_X_train_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = imputed_X_train_plus[col].isnull()
    imputed_X_test_plus[col + '_was_missing'] = imputed_X_test_plus[col].isnull()
    imputed_final_test_plus[col + 'was_missing'] = imputed_final_test_plus[col].isnull()
```